# With AspectJ, is there any way to get a callback when the Aspect is registered?

Tags: aspectj

I'm interested in running some code as soon as a Java application is started.  I'm using AspectJ's load-time weaving and would ideally like to piggy-back on this.

Is there an event that I can hook into when an Aspect is registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using the standard aspectj syntax (not @AspectJ), then i believe all aspects should be `new`'ed, so you can simply do it in the constructor of the aspect.